# How can i find which domain requests an iframe from my server and save domain on database

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a set of various websites requesting an `iframe` html file from my server for various reasons

Is it possible to track `onload` which domain requests the `iframe` and then save it on a database.

If the domain already exists then don't add it to the database.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the domain that requests the contents for the iframe, it is the user's browser.

There is a slight chance to see which page this iframe is on: The referrer (mistakenly misspelled in the standard document as "referer", so every browser had to copy this typo), available in PHP via $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

You can try and parse the domain from there, best by using [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse-url).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of jQuery's [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) functionality and PHP's [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables:

```
$.post("collect.php", { source: "<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>" } );
```

Your collect script could then check the database to see existing references to the source and enter a new one if required. An example using PDO:

```
if (isset($_POST['source']) && $source = $_POST['source']) {

   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

   // Be sure to sanitize $source

   if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE source = $source")->rowCount() == 0) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`time`, `source`) VALUES(?, ?)");
      $stmt->execute(array(time(), $source));
   }

}
```