# I need to know, who is framing my website?

Tags: iframe

I just need to know who is framing my site?
I just want to know the web address.
is there any way to find it out?

- I don't want to break frames, I just want to know who is framing.

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably get a general idea by looking at referrals from a traffic monitoring service/framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948327/456188 for preventing it....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539301/456188 for the only (and a very weak) way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739035/371228), you can get the "parent" URL by doing

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ?
    document.referrer: document.location;
```

You could then (for example) log this URL as a Google Analytics event:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
    'framed',
    location.pathname + location.search, // the URL of the iframe (your page)
    url, // the URL of the hosting page
    0,
    true]);
```